# testNG: Class Level group dependency does not work

Tags: java, testing, testng

My goal is to have a test run first within a suite.
I wanted to use the dependency on group feature.

I have the following structure:

```
@Test(groups={"init"})
public class TestConfig
{
     @BeforeSuite
     public void setup()
     {
           SuiteManager.instance().init(...);
     }
}
```

Then the class that invokes the dependency:

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups={"init"})
public class SingleTargetCreateTester 
{
           @Test
           public void testSingleTarget()
           {
            ....
           }
}
```

TestSuite.xml

```
<suite name="My Test Suite">
    <test name="SingleTargetTester">
        <parameter name="target_quantity" value="2" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.integration.testers.TestConfig" />
            <class name="com.integration.testers.SingleTargetCreateTester" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

It does enter the TestConfig first, but then when running the SingleTargetCreateTester it fails with the following error:

```
DependencyMap::Method "SingleTargetCreateTester.testSingleTarget()[pri:0, instance:com.integration.testers.SingleTargetCreateTester@2353f67e]" depends on nonexistent group "init"
```

It seems to not recognize the init group.

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @BeforeSuite is run at the start of a suite and just once.  You can remove the groups from  TestConfig.  Just keep the TestConfig class in the xml.  That should be it.  Remove the depends on from the other classes as well.

You can add as many classes as you want.  Testng would take into account the entire xml and then make a map of execution in which beforesuite would be executed just once.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use dependencies if you just want to execute your "setup" method before all your tests. Remove class level annotations and make your "SingleTargetCreateTester" to extend "TestConfig". that's it.

Comment: I didn't show the whole XMl but the reason i need that is because i have multiple test classes. If i extend, all of them will run the TestConfig which is not what i want in this use case

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your test from xml file or from test file. It looks like from test file?
Try from xml file.